# how to get user's random friend in facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, random

I have a friendlist that displays all of user's facebook friends. 
What I actually want is to display only **one** friend at a time, selected randomly.
is there any way to do so?

```
<?  
    foreach ($friends as $friend) 
    {
         echo "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" . $friend['id'] ."/picture'><br>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
  $friend_count = count($friends);
  $random_friend_num = rand(0,$friend_count-1);
  $random_friend = $friends[$random_friend_num];
  echo "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" . $random_friend['id']  ."/picture'><br>";
?>
```

The code is pretty much self explanatory..

- Get Friend count
- get Random number in range 0 to friendCount
- paste Random friend

If my answer is what you needed, feel free to accept it :)

Comment: it looks self explanatory, but it doesn't work.
I have used the following to define $friends.
$friends=$facebook->api('/me/friends');
 $friends=$friends['data'];
maybe, it's an issue?

Comment: hey, I fixed it. I added ['id'] in: 
echo "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" . $random_friend['id'] ."/picture'><br>";

thank you very much for your help